# Installed Django Allauth, can't find login page

Tags: django, django-allauth, django-1.7

I have just installed Django Allauth according to the documentation, with the aim of just enabling normal account login (no social for now). When I go to:

```
http://localhost:8000/accounts/
```

I get this:

```
Using the URLconf defined in seven.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
^accounts/ ^ ^signup/$ [name='account_signup']
^accounts/ ^ ^login/$ [name='account_login']
^accounts/ ^ ^logout/$ [name='account_logout']
^accounts/ ^ ^password/change/$ [name='account_change_password']
^accounts/ ^ ^password/set/$ [name='account_set_password']
^accounts/ ^ ^inactive/$ [name='account_inactive']
^accounts/ ^ ^email/$ [name='account_email']
^accounts/ ^ ^confirm-email/$ [name='account_email_verification_sent']
^accounts/ ^ ^confirm-email/(?P<key>\w+)/$ [name='account_confirm_email']
^accounts/ ^ ^confirm_email/(?P<key>\w+)/$
^accounts/ ^ ^password/reset/$ [name='account_reset_password']
^accounts/ ^ ^password/reset/done/$ [name='account_reset_password_done']
^accounts/ ^ ^password/reset/key/(?P<uidb36>[0-9A-Za-z]+)-(?P<key>.+)/$ [name='account_reset_password_from_key']
^accounts/ ^ ^password/reset/key/done/$ [name='account_reset_password_from_key_done']
^admin/
The current URL, accounts/, didn't match any of these.
```

However `http://localhost:8000/accounts/login/` just redirect back to localhost. It seems like it finds the allauth urls, but don't know what to do with it.

Here is my settings file: http://pastebin.com/bc3yqiwb. Im using Django 1.7c3

Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe you are already logged in. First load the logout url i.e. `/accounts/logout/` and then `/accounts/login/`